# The implication that the small category does not need to have TOTALITY (closure)?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, set-theory, abelian-categories, monoidal-categories

1. What is the implication and the importance of demanding that the [small category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_(mathematics)) does not need to have TOTALITY?
2. Although it is not obvious to me, but it seems that [TOTALITY iff closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_(mathematics)) (can you also explain this fact?).

For a small category, this demands that

- [Totality: No required](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function).
- Associativity: Yes.
- Identity : Yes.
- Invertibility: No required.
- Commutativity: No required.

Demanding invertibility or not makes the difference because it implies if $a$ is in the cateogry, there may not exist $a^{-1}$ such that $$a \cdot a^{-1} =1.$$

Demanding totality seems just a viewpoint on what is chosen to be

- the domain $X$ and the codomain $Y$
- the domain of definition $S$, and the range of $f(S)$, with $f$ as a functor between objects $s \in S$ and $f(s) \in f(S)$.

Suppose we chose to define $X=S$ and $Y=f(S)$, then I see that the Category here must also have TOTALITY. So TOTALITY seems to be a viewpoint on the definitions of the domain $X$ and the codomain $Y$. You can choose to have TOTALITY if  $X=S$ and $Y=f(S)$.

So why and what importance I missed on that the [totality is No required for a category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function)?

Answer (score 2):

Saying that composition is partial just means that, for arbitrary morphisms $f, g \in \mathrm{Mor}(\mathbf C)$, the composite $g \circ f$ may or may not exist: it exists precisely if $\mathrm{codom}(f) = \mathrm{dom}(g)$. If you instead present a category as having hom-sets indexed by the objects, then we have a family of total composition operations. E.g. given objects $X, Y, Z \in \mathbf C$, we have a total composition operations ${\circ}_{X, Y, Z} : \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf C}(Y, Z) \times \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf C}(X, Y)$.

Asking for the composition operation in the first presentation to be total would be any two morphisms could be composed, even if they don't share a domain/codomain.

These two presentations of the definition of category are both common. Presenting composition as a partial operation on all morphisms leads to the notion of [internal category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_category), whereas presenting it as indexed by objects leads to the notion of [enriched category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enriched_category).

Finally, note that if every morphism is invertible, you get what is known as a [groupoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupoid).

Comment: thanks so much I voted +1

Comment: What is Mor of category? (sorry it is not easy for me to follow even the first sentence... when you start with "composition is partial")

Comment: Also I asked two more questions that maybe you can offer some advices -- https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4089180/141334, and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4089176/141334 -- thank you!

Comment: @anniemarieheart: $\mathrm{Mor}(\mathbf C)$ is the set/class of morphisms of the category (with any domain and codomain).