# Morphisms of a category can be regarded as the objects of a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, abelian-categories, monoidal-categories

Here is a category with a collection of objects $$A, B, C$$ and collection of morphisms denoted $$f, \quad g, \quad g ∘ f,$$ and the loops are the identity arrows. This category is typically denoted by a boldface **3**.

It is often said that:

- the **group** requires **Totality (Closure), Associativity, Identity, Invertibility.**
- the **category** requires only **Associativity, Identity.**

### My question:

Is it correct to view the morphisms of category (here $f, \quad g, \quad g ∘ f,$) as the group elements of group?

If so, it seems that the **morphisms** (but not the objects) of a category becomes the **objects** (group elements) of a group as a set.

$$\text{the morphisms of a category can be regarded as the objects of a group?}$$
Is this the correct way and the only way to go from the category to the group theory? Or can it be also that
$$\text{the objects of a category can be regarded as the objects of a group?}$$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are not totally lost but there is a fact that you are not thinking about. What do happen with the inverse? I mean, in the definition of group you claim that $\exists 1$ (Identity element), the operation of $G$ (lets denote it by *) is associative and for each $g \in G$ $\exists g^{-1}$ (simetric or inverse element) such that $g*g^{-1}=g^{-1}*g=1$

If you choose morphisims of a category as elements and composition like operation, It is true that composition is associative and the definition of category claim that exists identity morphisim that can be the identity element of the group but there is no reason to think that for each morphisim $f$ $\exists f^{-1}$ so your morphisims do not form a group in general They form a monoid unless you establish more conditions.

Just think in $\textbf{Set}$ category, in general an application between sets do not need to have inverse.

Comment: thanks I voted up -- I agree that the category is not a group. But my point is that how to view the category + something to become a group. And how to view the group + something to become a category.

Comment: But in this case the group seems not require "objects of category" but only the "morphisims of category." Why is that?

Comment: See a group like a category is easy you can think it like a category that only have an object (so it has less importance) and the elements of the group are the morphisims of the category from the object inself, where this category has the particularity that all its morphisims are isomorphisims

Comment: It is better explained on “Basic category theory” Tom Leinster if you want to take a look

Comment: Maybe I am not so clear , in this case let me know and I try to write another answer about it more precisely

Answer (score 1):

In order to answer correctly to the comment:

-Groups like categories with only one object:

$(G,*)$ a group it can be seen as a category $\mathscr {A}$ Where $Ob(\mathscr{A})=\{A\}$ and the morphisims are the elements of the group.[image]

The composition is the operation * of $G$ that according group definition will be associative and will exists identity element.

In these case we will have an extra propriety in $\mathscr{A}$ ; every morphisim will be an isomorphisim because every $g\in G$ has inverse.
[image]

If you want to do the inverse correspondence I think you need to establish that in your category all map is an isomophisim, maybe a way of think is category + inverse maps = group but you still need the condition of unique object because in other case you could have elements of the group that can not be operated and this does not happen in groups.